# Undergraduate Math Major Wanting to Learn Physics

Tags: soft-question, education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations)

So I'm a Junior level math major.  I've seen some abstract algebra, some differential geometry, and some lie theory.  I'm currently working through some standard topology.  I don't at all claim to be an "expert" in any of the above, but I'll attest that I have some decent mathematical maturity.

I've always had a soft spot for physics, and I wanted to develop my knowledge of it much more formally.  Particularly things like general relativity and quantum mechanics seem very cool, but I'm lamentably pretty ignorant of them.  Given my somewhat okay math background, is there a good starting point for someone like me?

Comment: Hi AsinglePANCAKE, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I think what you're asking for is more or less provided by our book recommendation thread.

Comment: I would add that their are numerous youtube lectures by Leonard Susskind covering many of these topics.  General relativity is one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbmf0bB38h0